# Ruby on rails - access model data within another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

I want to access a column from OtherModel.rb to MyModel.rb. Is that possible?

this is what it looks like if the data that I want to access is located within the model it self. and this works just fine

```
//MyModel.rb

def to_param
  self.name
end
```

but I don't know how to access data from other model.
Here is an example of what I want:

```
//MyModel.rb

def to_param
  OtherModel.name
end
```

Comment: its possible to access instances of other models, but its really not good practice.

Comment: may I know how to do it? I'm very desperate right now

Comment: Which instance of other model?

Comment: Hi @FrederickCheung, what do you mean? I'm sorry I'm a newbie in rails

Comment: Well presumably there are many rows in the table for OtherModel. Of all those, which one's name attribute do you want?

Comment: Voting to reopen as it's a fundamental question, especially to newcomers to the framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Model-ception!!

---

**Objects**

The best way to describe the issue you have is to outline that Ruby (& Rails by virtue of being built on top of the Ruby language) is [object-orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Contrary to popular belief, *object-oriented* is more than just a buzzword - it means that every element of your application should be constructed around *objects*. Objects are essentially "variables" which have a collection of attributes & other data attached to them:

[image]

In Rails, an object is created as an *instance* of a model (class)

---

**Fix**

When you're calling `OtherModel.name`, you're not initializing an *instance* of the relevant class, hence meaning you will not be able to display any of the attributes it has

To ensure this issue can be remedied, you need to **ensure you load an instance of your `OtherModel` object**, to ensure you're able to call the relevant data:

```
#app/models/my_model.rb
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   def to_param
      return OtherModel.first.name #-> returns first instance of `OtherModel` & then displays "name"
   end
end
```

---

**Associations**

A better option is to harness [`ActiveRecord Associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#why-associations-questionmark):

```
#app/models/my_model.rb
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :other_models
end

#app/models/other_model.rb
Class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :my_model
end
```

This means you'll be able to call the following:

```
@my_model = MyModel.find 1
@my_model.other_models.each do |other|
   puts other.name
end
```

See how the ActiveRecord associations creates an *instance* of the associated model? This allows you to call it from the instance of your "parent" model without having to re-initialize it

--

**Delegate**

You may also be able to use the [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method depending on your association setup:

```
#app/models/my_model.rb
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :other_model
    delegate :name, to: :other_model, prefix: true
end

#app/models/other_model.rb
Class OtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :my_models
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@my_model = MyModel.find 1
@my_model.other_model_name
```

It must be noted the `delegate` method *only* works with `belongs_to` relationships

Comment: Hi.. is it possible to add a filter? for example return OtherModel.where("other_model_id = ?" my_model_id).first.name     thanks in advance :)

Comment: The "filter" you refer to can EASILY be achieved with an ActiveRecord association, as I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

OtherModel.new will create a new instance of OtherModel.

Or you can use OtherModel.all.first for first record of OtherModel. Depending on the context, we can access name column through any instance

Provided name is the name of column of OtherModel

**MyModel.rb**

```
def to_param
  OtherModel.new.name
  OtherModel.all.first.name
end
```